# Include controller methods in emails in a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, controller, actionmailer

I am trying to email a monthly report which is simple the current month's income compared to the last months.

I have all of that working in my report controller (which references another model called Clinical):

```
# Clinical income by month report
@clinical_income_by_month = Clinical.select(%q{date_format(transactiondate, '%Y') as year, date_format(transactiondate, '%M') as month, sum(LineBalance) as income})
                               .where(:payments => 0)
                               .where('linebalance <> ?', 0)
                               .where('analysiscode <> ?', 213)
                               .group(:monthyear)
```

I then have a partial for the table with the data:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns"><h5>This months income so far is <span style="font-size:1.2em"class="<% if @clinical_income_by_month.first.income >= @clinical_income_by_month.first(:offset => 12).income %>green<% else %>red<% end %> radius label"><%= number_to_currency(@clinical_income_by_month.first.income, :unit => "&pound;", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ",") %></span></h5> <%= @clinical_income_by_month.first.month %> <%= @clinical_income_by_month.first(:offset => 12).year %>'s income was <%= number_to_currency(@clinical_income_by_month.first(:offset => 12).income, :unit => "&pound;", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ",") %>.</div>
  </div>
<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Income</th>
  </tr>  
  <% @clinical_income_by_month.each do |c| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.year %></td>
    <td><%= c.month %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(c.income, :unit => "&pound;", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ",") %></td>
  </tr>    
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I would like to be able to pull that partial into my email, or if that's not possible, I would like to show the value of the last income.

```
<%= @clinical_income_by_month.first.income %>
```

My email code looks like this:

```
Finance Report
================================================
<%= number_to_currency(@clinical_income_by_month.first.income) %>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
1.9.2-p318 :009 > UserMailer.finance_report().deliver
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
from   /Users/dannymcclelland/Projects/premvet/app/views/user_mailer/finance_report.text.erb:3:in  `_app_views_user_mailer_finance_report_text_erb___4501411113534248604_70358523362460'
```

It works when I pull a value from the standard method:

```
<%= number_to_currency(Clinical.first.UserID) %>
```

but not when I call it from the @clinical_income_by_month report I created.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Actually I don't see where is `@clinical_income_by_vet` initialized, only `@clinical_income_by_month`. Is it a misprint here?

Comment: Whoops, well spotted. Updated to show that I wrote the question wrong, it should shoe @clinical_income_by_month not vet. Thanks.

Comment: You should initialize all the variables you want to use in the view in `UserMailer.finance_report()` method

Comment: Like this? `UserMailer.finance_report(c.month,c.year,c.income).deliver`

Comment: added as an answer as there is more formatting available :)

Comment: I would actually start by moving this method to the model. That way you can call Clinical.income_by_month(x, y, z). Then I would look at @alony's approach. It certainly seems like the variable isn't being passed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this:

**in user_mailer.rb**

```
def finance_report(clinical_income_by_month)

  @clinical_income_by_month = clinical_income_by_month

  ... # all you had here before

end
```

And **in the controller** call it this way:

```
UserMailer.finance_report(@clinical_income_by_month).deliver
```

Comment: When adding your suggesstion to the user_mailer.rb and then trying to send the email from the rails console using your suggested controller code, I get 'ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your @clinical_income_by_month is nil. That means the select query is not returning values as you think it should. This is a model problem. Instead of checking the views, you should fire up the "rails console" and see whether the query returns the values you want.

Comment: I don't see the situation when the relation would return nil. If there are no results - it will be an empty collection

Comment: @clinical_income_by_month.first is nil.

Just like [].first == nil.